# How to use simple math in Slick Queries

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I have this query I want to convert to slick:

```
SELECT (date_part('epoch', SUM(end_time - start_time))*1000)::bigint FROM v2_game
```

I could live with the cast happening in scala and not in the database, but I am at a loss for how to do the subtraction. end_time and start_time are both Dates, represented as timestamps in the database. So far I have this:

```
val datePart = SimpleFunction.binary[String, Date, Double]("date_part")
  val q = for {
    g <- Games
  } yield datePart("epoch", g.startTime)
```

So what how to subtract/add values? Google returns little to no results on my searches, either this is really simple or nobody else wants to use a bit of math in queries.

I am using Slick 1.0.1 with postgres sql

Answer (score 1):

You may look into `age` function in postgres. It computes interval between to dates.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: this sql indeed returns the exact same result I need: SELECT (date_part('epoch', AVG(age(end_time, start_time)))*1000)::bigint FROM v2_game; However there is still the *1000 and in general I still need to know how to do math. I have quite a few other queries that do other kinds of math, that cannot use age()

Comment: Then you may be interested in `SimpleBinaryOperator` and `SimpleExpression`. I have no experience with them, but based on names and sources they may help you

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [slick-pg library](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg). It has extensions to slick to support postgres specific stuff, including date / time manipulation. If you add its [DateTime support](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/date) you can write, e.g

```
val q = for {
  g <- Games
} yield (g.endTime - g.startTime).part("epoch")
```

which would be equivalent to

```
SELECT date_part('epoch', endTime - startTime) FROM games
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there are extensions to do math: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.NumericColumnExtensionMethods

However these seem not to work with dates and also require the involved values to be of the exact same type. So with this knowledge I now use the age function, thanks to 1esha, and ended up with this:

```
  val datePartLong = SimpleFunction.binary[String, Date, Long]("date_part")
  val age = SimpleFunction.binary[Date, Date, Date]("age")

  val q = Query((for {
    g <- Games
  } yield datePartLong("epoch", age(g.endTime, g.startTime)) * 1000L).sum)
```

A small caveat is that this calls the date_part method on every row and sums afterwards, but I cannot find a way to do it the other way around, it simply doesn't work out type wise.
According to explain the query costs are 164 for the slick query and 139 for the pure sql. I guess this is okay, no need to do premature optimization any further. :)